# How can I draw an additional horizontal grid line with a specific value in Google Bar chart (Not average value)

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How can I draw an additional horizontal grid line with a specific value in Google Bar chart. The line I want to draw is not the average. It is a specific value.

**What I am getting**
[image]

**What I need**
[image]

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

This my data model:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" }, "TARGET GOAL"],
    ["Apr-19", 17, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["May-19", 32, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["Jun-19", 20, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["Jul-19", 22, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["Aug-19", 27, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["Sep-19", 26, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
    ["Oct-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
    ["Nov-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
    ["Dec-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
]);
```

And in `options` object I have this:

```
seriesType: 'bars',
series:{
   3: {
        type: 'line'
      }
}
```

Since **25** is the value I want to be rendered as a line and it is in the 4th position.

And finally

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("container_id"));
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT-2 Complete script:**

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_ebcg_unitary);

function drawChart_ebcg_unitary() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" }, "TARGET GOAL"],
        ["Apr-19", 17, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["May-19", 32, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
            ["Jun-19", 20, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Jul-19", 22, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Aug-19", 27, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Sep-19", 26, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Oct-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
        ["Nov-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
        ["Dec-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
             {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
             },
        2]);

        var options = {
        chartArea: {
                    left: 50,
                    width: "90%",
                    height: 250
        },

        title: "",
        width: '100%',
        height: 350,
        bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
        legend: {position: "none"},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series:{
            1: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            title: 'SALES UNITS'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'MONTH'
        },
        annotations: {
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: 12,
                bold: true
            },
            alwaysOutside: true
        }
    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("ecbg_unitary"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}

jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    drawChart_ebcg_unitary();
});
```

**EDIT 3: Average line**
How can I make the average line (please see screenshot) value (25) to appear only once, i.e at the end of the line rather than showing it on every month's column. This needs to look similar as in the screenshot under (**What I need**) section. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `ComboChart`, which allows you to draw series of different types.

in the options, set the main `seriesType`.
then use the `series` option, to change the type of a specific series...

```
{
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {
    1: {
      type: 'line'
    }
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_ebcg_unitary);

function drawChart_ebcg_unitary() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" }, "TARGET GOAL"],
        ["Apr-19", 17, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["May-19", 32, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
            ["Jun-19", 20, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Jul-19", 22, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Aug-19", 27, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Sep-19", 26, "#c4c4c4", 25], 
        ["Oct-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
        ["Nov-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
        ["Dec-19", 18, "#008600", 25], 
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,
             {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
             },
        2, 3]);

        var options = {
        chartArea: {
                    left: 50,
                    width: "90%",
                    height: 250
        },

        title: "",
        width: '100%',
        height: 350,
        bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
        legend: {position: "none"},
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series:{
            1: {
                type: 'line'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            title: 'SALES UNITS'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'MONTH'
        },
        annotations: {
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Arial, sans-serif',
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: 12,
                bold: true
            },
            alwaysOutside: true
        }
    };


    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("ecbg_unitary"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="ecbg_unitary"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to display the annotation for the average only once,
use your own calculation for the annotation,
and only return a value if the row index equals the last row...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  },
  2, 3, {
    calc: function(dt, row) {
      var annotation = null;
      if (row === (dt.getNumberOfRows() - 1)) {
        annotation = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
      }
      return annotation;
    },
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }
]);
```

Comment: This one is not working. I have edited mu question. Please see once.

Comment: in your case, the series number would still be 1, the x-axis and style role do not count as a series. changed answer above...

Comment: Sorry for bothering! Even with 1 I am not able to get the horizontal line. Edited my question with the full script block. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: just needed to add the line column (`, 3`) to the view, changed answer above

Comment: GREAT!! Thanks a lot again. :)

Comment: Come back again!! Sorry. I updated my original question with another question under "Edit 3". Is there a way to do accomplish the same?

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat. I will remember. Fortunately I made it already exactly the same way you suggested. :)